# Zxing Android - How to get scanner/camera not in fullscreen?

Tags: android, zxing

I only recently started developing under android and I like it but yesterday I ran into this problem with zxing and it is driving me crazy and I really can't seem to find a solution. I am using zxing to scan QR codes, it works but the scanner goes fullscreen when I launch it and I would like it to be displayed in one fragment, not take the whole screen. I am developing an app on a tablet with two fragments as below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment android:name="com.example.mlambole.fragapp.InfoFragment"
        android:id="@+id/info_fragment"
        android:background="#B89470"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <fragment android:name="com.example.mlambole.fragapp.DetailFragment"
        android:id="@+id/detail_fragment"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The class DetailFragment takes 2/3 third of the screen on the right and that is the place where I would like the scanner to show, only in these 2/3.

The DetailFragment class looks like as of now

```
public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.detail_view, container, false);

        Button buttonScan = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button_scan);
        buttonScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                clickScan(v);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public void clickScan(View view)
    {

        IntentIntegrator integrator = IntentIntegrator.forFragment(this);
        integrator.initiateScan(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        System.out.println("onActivityResult");
        if (scanResult != null) {
            String scanContent = scanResult.getContents();
            String scanFormat = scanResult.getFormatName();
        }
    }

}
```

The MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getActionBar().hide();
        setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

I use Android Studio and Zxing with Maven as follow

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url "https://raw.github.com/embarkmobile/zxing-android-minimal/mvn-repo/maven-repository/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Supports Android 4.0.3 and later (API level 15)
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-minimal:2.0.0@aar'

    // Supports Android 2.1 and later (API level 7), but not optimal for later Android versions.
    // If you only plan on supporting Android 4.0.3 and up, you don't need to include this.
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-legacy:2.0.0@aar'

    // Convenience library to launch the scanning and encoding Activities.
    // It automatically picks the best scanning library from the above two, depending on the
    // Android version and what is available.
    compile 'com.embarkmobile:zxing-android-integration:2.0.0@aar'

    // Version 3.0.x of zxing core contains some code that is not compatible on Android 2.2 and earlier.
    // This mostly affects encoding, but you should test if you plan to support these versions.
    // Older versions e.g. 2.2 may also work if you need support for older Android versions.
    compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Is there a zxing genius out there ?? please

Thanks